# giving AD users shared email account

Tags: active-directory, email, exchange

I have a microsoft platform, with active directory and exchange.

Normally, all AD users are assigned mailboxes associated to that userid. Our organization employs many transient personnel, who come for a few months, then leaves. Usually one person replaces the next.

My problem is exchange email. When Assigning a user an entry in Active Directory, Exchange tabs allow me to create a mailbox, usually personalized for the user by user id. For example: user1 would normally be given email address user1@organization.com.

What I need to do is have a general exchange mailbox, that I can assign multiple users to, to which is their primary mailbox, not a secondary or a mailbox that is given privilidges to.

This way, I can create user1 with email gen1@organization.com, and when user1 leaves I can create user2 with email gen1@organization.com. I won't have to burn licenses or mailbox space on user1@... and user2@....

Thank you very much. Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like [Shared Mailboxes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150498%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).

[This link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2015/02/06/single-click-mailbox-conversion.aspx) might do what you're looking for--it's about transitioning a mailbox to a shared mailbox when someone leaves, and back to a single mailbox when you get the next person.  It's for Office365, and you didn't say which version of Exchange you were using, but [it looks like you can do something similar with powershell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj710164%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Katherine.  And your right, I forgot to mention we are Exchange 2010, and looking to go to Exchange 2013 later in the year.

Comment: Does this change things?  Evan

Comment: Public folders (as opposed to shared mailboxes) are handled differently in 2013, so if you're thinking of using them instead you might want to keep that in mind.  As for converting mailboxes from user mailboxes to shared mailboxes, there's powershell to do that in 2010 as well.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb201749%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx